# Hypothesis test for truncated distributed random variables in Bayesian Regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, truncation, truncated-normal-distribution

As per the recommendation, I am re-framing my questions.

I am doing a Bayesian Regression where the parameters are truncated at zero ($0< \beta < \infty$, Assuming prior to follow truncated normal distribution). I need to prove the significance of the estimated parameters for the same. Do I have to go for conventional hypothesis testing and $p$ value calculation same as the frequentist regression approach? If not then do I have to go for Bayes Factor analysis? and do I need to compute the credible intervals for the estimated parameters?

Moreover, in case of frquentist regression approach how to proceed for significance testing of the parameters estimated? Do I need to use truncated t-distribution for finding the test statistic and p value calculation?

Comment: Do you have a parameter that has a truncated normal distribution, or data that has a truncated normal distribution with several parameters (e.g., the truncation point, $\mu, \sigma^2$)?

Comment: I am implementing a constrained Bayesian regression where the regression coefficients are allocated truncated normal distribution at zero (i.e. $0<\beta<\infty$)... I am thinking about the significance testing of those coefficients...

Comment: If you are constraining $\beta > 0$ in your prior, you already know that $\beta > 0$, so no "significance testing" need be done.  Furthermore, "significance testing" and "p-values" are concepts from classical statistics, and don't fit well into the Bayesian paradigm.  And, in addition, "what should be the recommended distribution of the sample distribution" makes no sense.  Are you asking what the distribution of the data conditional upon the parameters should be?  Obviously there's no way we can answer that, given no knowledge of the problem you are facing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. Pardon my ignorance, are significance testing and p value approach, completely irrelevant in Bayesian?  But then how to be sure about the significance of the estimated coefficients? Are the type-I and type II errors also not relevant in case of Bayesian estimation of coefficients? and moreover, credible intervals are frequently estimated on the parameters based on the posterior of estimated coefficients... Does it suffice regarding the significance testing?